# How to automatically resize an array of images within a fixed container with no overflow, no scrolling, no media-queries?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, css-grid

I receive an array of square images from an API for display in a React app.  The number of images vary between 1 and 14.  The dimensions of the images I receive from the API are either 200px, 512px, or 600px square.  The displayed images have corresponding jackpot denominations and jackpot amounts displayed underneath the images, and a title above them.  The display can show from 1-5 denominations and corresponding amounts, which all must be the same size - shrinking these is not an option.

My app will be displayed in a place of business, on a 1920H x 1080W screen, with no scrolling possible.  There will be no screen resizing possible, and therefore no media queries.

The display will rotate every ten seconds so that a new set of images will be displayed.  I have attached a link to a CodeSandbox link - https://codesandbox.io/s/jackpot-ufs5t - with a rough replica of my app (no rotation, no API calls), with basic simulated data in the imageList.js file, which acts as a fake API.

I want the images to fit in a container near the top of the screen, below the title and above the jackpot denominations/amounts.  If there are a few images (6 or less), I want them to be a certain height & width (303px square seems to look good).  If there are more than 6 images, I want the height and width to decrease proportionally so they all fit within the container, between the title and the jackpot amounts.

Everything looks pretty when there's only a few images and 1-3 jackpot denominations.  However the worst case scenario - 14 images & 5 jackpot denominations - is a disaster.

Flexbox with flex-wrap enabled seems good at auto-fitting the images and making them smaller if the container size shrinks.  But that's not the case here, the more images there are, they just overlap what's above or below them.

I used CSS-Grid in the attached CodeSandbox example, which I also cannot get to work.

Using the imageList file in the CodeSandbox, commenting and uncommenting the data will vary the number of images and jackpot amounts shown.

What I have done to make it work (not shown in the CodeSandbox) is to conditionally assign different classes to the images and container based on every different combination of the lengths of the images array and the jackpot array.  But I feel there has got to be a better way, with either Flexbox or CSS-Grid to automatically shrink the size of the square images, based solely on how many there are.  Am I wrong?

I am currently only worried about the vertical display (portrait), not the horizontal (landscape) view.

CodeSandbox link again: https://codesandbox.io/s/jackpot-ufs5t

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, define a grid inside your `container-logos` class and having the logos to have 100% of the width  and height of the virtual space created by css grid.

So basically, all you need to do is:

- add  `grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(79px, 1fr));` to the already existing `.container-logos` class.
- Remove eveything you have in your `.logo` class and add `height: 100%; width: 100%;`.

Here is also a quick example of what I've described:

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;    
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
}

.container-logos{
  max-height: 50vh;
  max-width: 50vw;
  width:50vw;
  height:50vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(45px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(45px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.logo{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-logos">

  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="logo"></div>

</div>
```

You can also try to delete/add a few "logos" from my example to watch them enlarge/shrink sizes, according to available space.

Also, here is a quick shot of how I could get your example by doing the explained above:

[image: Example modified]

Comment: Pedro, thank you for the answer.  Did you mean that I should wrap the <img>s in a <div> with the class="logo"?  If I apply the 100% width/height directly to the image, they are no longer square - they get tall and skinny.  If I wrap each <img> tag in a <div class="logo">, that seems to work better, although when there are only a few logo images, they are too small.   It would be great if when there were 1-6 logos, they would be large enough fill the space.  Don't know if that's possible, but I'll play around with it.  This was better than anything I came up with - thank you!